# How do I convert a custom function to handle spill arrays (excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

I need a function that produces a list of sheet names, I already have one that can turn sheet numbers into sheet names but it doesnt handle arrays

The function I would like to convert is

```
Function SHEETNAME(number As Variant) As String
    SHEETNAME = Sheets(number).Name
End Function
```

I would like it to accept the input along the lines of

```
=SHEETNAME(SEQUENCE(SHEET()-1))
```

This would output a list of all the sheets before the current one

so for example (assuming default names) if we are on Sheet4 the output would be {Sheet1; Sheet2; Sheet3}

Comment: Welcome! I'm not sure I understand the purpose of SEQUENCE() in your formula. If you write your own function, then why not just pass it the parameter "up to the sheet with the number such and such inclusive"?

Comment: @JohnSUN I guess I could have a formula that lists all the sheets
then use CHOOSEROWS() or DROP() to remove the unwanted ones, but I don't know how to do that (I'm very new to VB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need sheet names from the first to the specified one, then using SEQUENCE() is not justified, the macro can easily loop within the specified boundaries:

```
Function getListNames(endSheet As Long) As Variant
Dim aResult As Variant
Dim i As Long
    ReDim aResult(1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        aResult(i, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
        If i >= endSheet Then Exit For
    Next i
    getListNames = aResult
End Function
```

Call it with `{=GETLISTNAMES(SHEET()-1)}`

Comment: Thank you that sort of works although gives some zeros in places but I now know enough to sort it.

I've removed the end sheet value and exit.
And then I just use `DROP(GETLISTNAMES(),-1)` to get a list of all but the last sheet
or `CHOOSEROWS(GETLISTNAMES(),SHEET())` / `INDEX(GETLISTNAMES(),SHEET())` if I want the name of the current sheet

Comment: Ignore that also comment all I needed was `Application.Volatile`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your problem is.

- `SEQUENCE` will => an array of numbers
- Loop through the `SEQUENCE` converting each number to a sheet name
- Store the **SheetNames** in some convenient object (`array`, `arraylist`, `collection`, `dictionary`)
- Equate the function name to the array (transpose if you want a vertical output)

*It is not clear what you mean by "before the current one". You should be aware that sheet numbers represent the order of the sheets as seen at the bottom of the Excel window and will change if you re-order those sheets.*

eg:

```
Option Explicit
Function SheetNames(SN) As Variant
    Dim AL As Object
    Dim V

Set AL = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
For Each V In SN
    AL.Add ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(V).Name
Next V

'Transpose => vertical array
SheetNames = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(AL.toarray)
    
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it will do what I want but I'm getting a #VALUE error with both single value and array input

And yes I'm aware changes to the order or new sheets will change the results of the formula

Comment: @user294133 You will definitely get an error with a single input, as you wrote you wanted an array input. And it works here without error using a formula of the type you show in your question. With this limited information, I cannot diagnose the problem. But I see you have an answer that works for you anyway.

Comment: yea sorry about that should have clarified that I wanted it to do what it currently does and handle array input

But yea it seems a different route was better